# Updating a mySQL table efficiently?

Tags: mysql, performance, computer-science, database-administration

I'm looking for a bit of general advice on an approach here.

Say I have a table layout that is like:

```
Name | 1hr  | 2hr  | 3hr  | 4hr
---------------------------------
Joe  | 23   | 12   | 45   | 9
```

The hours refer to an hour ago. Or 3 hours ago. And I will be updating this data every hour. I'll be doing this with many rows. Now each time I update I will move the values to the right. So 1hr becomes 2hr etc. And 1hr is then inserted as new.

My questions is this, instead of updating each cell and then the new value is inserted what would be the most efficient way of doing this? I will be using Java and JDBC as to control these operations.

My initial though is to treat it like you would a circular array. Have an extra cell to hold a pointer to the start. This would result in 2 updates per operations vs 4.

Is this a good approach or is there something better?

Comment: Once per hour? Don't even bother optimizing this. Unless you are the Facebook developer.

Comment: I would do it as a view or select query.  I wouldn't continually update the data.  It's costly and doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Perhaps you could normalize this and have a separate record for each hour?

Comment: You should read http://www.xarg.org/2009/09/fast-circular-buffer-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better approach would be to store another table:

```
Name | Time  | Value
--------------------
Joe  | 10:00 |  9
Joe  | 11:00 | 45
Joe  | 12:00 | 12
Joe  | 13:00 | 23
```

Then you don't have to do *anything* to update, you just add a new row when you want to add a value.

Comment: Ether second column should be DateTime, or there will be still `UPDATE` or `DELETE` involved